# How to integrated Enterprise Business Suite 11i or 12 with APEX 5.?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Can you help me How to integrated Enterprise Business Suite 11i or 12 with APEX 5.?
I just want create menu in ebs, and linking that to my apex application.

Any simple document or sample application for this.?

Thanks and regards,
M.C.

Comment: Please read these first then ask question what problem you have: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/apex-ebs-extension-white-paper-345780.pdf and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/apex-ebs-wp-cabot-consulting-169064.pdf

Comment: Hi @MuhammadMuazzam. I already followed those document. My link always back to EBS Login Page. I am still using Oracle Realese 11i.

Comment: Need help. I was follow http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/apex-ebs-wp-cabot-consulting-169064.pdf..